# Uploading scripts to run to non-local cluster using slurm?

Tags: bash, slurm

I am new to running on multiple cluster systems and I am stuck. I have a bash shell script (myjob.sh) and a secondary script to be executed (stuff.R). I am unsure of how, once I am logged on to the non-local cluster, to upload these files to be ran? "scp" is usually my go to for this sort of thing but I cannot figure out how to make the file move to the cluster. If I go into an interactive shell mode I can make the files using "nano" but I really need to figure this out without the interactive shell. I'm weirdly stuck in limbo. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Clusters usually have some shared storage mapped to the same place on all nodes. Try to find it and put your scripts there. From your machine to the cluster, `scp` is the solution, of course.

Comment: Contact your cluster's admin